# handling mailchimp's ajax query with js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I didn't use their API, I thought it would just easy with js, but I was wrong. After hours of battle, I found a way to handle the post-submission. below code check whether user submitted their email successfully.

```
function checkSuccess() {
      if ($('#mce-success-response').is(':visible')) {

         $('.ok_button').css('display','block');

      // window.clearInterval();

      }
    }

    window.setInterval(checkSuccess, 100);
```

but how to reset back? I wish to hide back the `ok` button when user focus back on the input bar, I couldn't found a way even I use clearInterval. Help.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you searching for? Why don't you use .focus()??

Comment: the setInterval is still running..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the interval id to the `clearInterval`. You may do it this way:

```
function checkSuccess() {
  if ($('#mce-success-response').is(':visible')) {

     $('.ok_button').css('display','block');

     window.clearInterval(window.checkSuccessTimer);

  }
}

window.checkSuccessTimer = window.setInterval(checkSuccess, 100);
```